# How to make a record from a sequence of values

Tags: clojure

I have a simple record definition, for example

```
(defrecord User [name email place])
```

What is the best way to make a record having it's values in a sequence

```
(def my-values ["John" "john@example.com" "Dreamland"])
```

I hoped for something like

```
(apply User. my-values)
```

but that won't work. I ended up doing:

```
(defn make-user [v]
  (User. (nth v 0) (nth v 1) (nth v 2)))
```

But I'm sensing there is some better way for achieving this...

Comment: and add on to the answers: 1.  Take a look at https://github.com/david-mcneil/defrecord2 the provide some extra stuff. 2. I think they plan some stuff like this in future clojure versions.

Comment: As a side note: You can use destructuring binding in your constructor function. Just for cosmetic reasons. (defn make-user [[n e p]] (User. n e p)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning: works only for literal sequables!** (see Mihał's comment)

Try this macro:

```
(defmacro instantiate [klass values] 
        `(new ~klass ~@values))
```

If you expand it with:

`(macroexpand '(instantiate User ["John" "john@example.com" "Dreamland"]))`

you'll get this:

`(new User "John" "john@example.com" "Dreamland")`

which is basically what you need.

And you can use it for instantiating other record types, or Java classes. Basically, this is just a class constructor that takes a one sequence of parameters instead of many parameters.

Comment: NB. this will only work if the `instantiate` macro receives a literal seqable of values. E.g. `(def vals ["John" "john@example.com" "Dreamland"])` followed by `(instantiate User vals)` will not work. Plus a macro can't be used with `apply`.

Comment: @Mihał: Thanks. I didn't think of that corner case. Luckily, in the cases when literal is used, apply isn't needed.

Comment: Not that I need it, but I found a nasty way which also works with non-literal seqable - `(defn instantiate [klass values] (eval (read-string (str "(new " (.getName klass) " " (let [s (str values)] (subs s 1 (- (.length s) 1))) ")"))))`

Answer (score 4):

the defrecord function creates a compiled class with some immutable fields in it. it's not a proper clojure functions (ie: not a class that implements iFn). If you want to call it's constructor with apply (which expects an iFun) you need to wrap it in an anonymous function so apply will be able to digest it.

`(apply #(User. %1 %2 %3 %4) my-values)`

it's closer to what you started with though your approach of defining a constructor with a good descriptive name has its own charm :)

from the [API](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defrecord):

```
Note that method bodies are
not closures, the local environment includes only the named fields,
and those fields can be accessed directy.
```

Comment: definitely like this more than my nth-y thing.. but still I have to note all expected arguments.. i'm looking for some general way which could be applied on any record definition... if there is one...

Answer (score 4):

Writing your own constructor function is probably the way to go.  As Arthur Ulfeldt said, you then have a function you can use as a function (e.g. with `apply`) rather than a Java-interop constructor call.

With your own constructor function you can also do argument validation or supply default arguments.  You gain another level of abstraction to work with; you can define `make-user` to return a hash-map for quick development, and if you later decide to change to records, you can do so without breaking everything.  You can write constructors with multiple arities, or that take keyword arguments, or do any number of other things.

```
(defn- default-user [name]
  (str (.toLowerCase name) "@example.com"))

(defn make-user
  ([name] (make-user name nil nil))
  ([name place] (make-user name nil place))
  ([name user place]
     (when-not name
       (throw (Exception. "Required argument `name` missing/empty.")))
     (let [user (or user (default-user name))]
       (User. name user place))))

(defn make-user-keyword-args [& {:keys [name user place]}]
  (make-user name user place))

(defn make-user-from-hashmap [args]
  (apply make-user (map args [:name :user :place])))

user> (apply make-user ["John" "john@example.com" "Somewhere"])
#:user.User{:name "John", :email "john@example.com", :place "Somewhere"}

user> (make-user "John")
#:user.User{:name "John", :email "john@example.com", :place nil}

user> (make-user-keyword-args :place "Somewhere" :name "John")
#:user.User{:name "John", :email "john@example.com", :place "Somewhere"}

user> (make-user-from-hashmap {:user "foo"})
; Evaluation aborted.
; java.lang.Exception: Required argument `name` missing/empty.
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple thing you can do is to make use of destructuring.

```
(defn make-user [[name email place]]
  (User. name email place))
```

Then you can just call it like this

```
(make-user ["John" "John@example.com" "Dreamland"])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Clojure 1.4**

defrecord now defines `->User` and `map->User` thus following in Goran's footstaps, one can now

```
(defmacro instantiate [rec args] `(apply ~(symbol (str "->" rec)) ~args))
```

which also works with non-literal sequences as in `(instantiate User my-values)`.
Alternatively, along the lines of `map->User` one can define a function `seq->User`

```
(defmacro def-seq-> [rec] `(defn ~(symbol (str "seq->" rec)) [arg#] (apply ~(symbol (str "->" rec)) arg#)))

(def-seq-> User)
```

which will allow `(seq->User my-values)`.

Comment: You can simply `(apply ->User values)`; `->User` is a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to call a Record constructor is with the Clojure symbol `->MyRecord` and that works just fine with `apply`.

```clj
(def my-values ["John" "john@example.com" "Dreamland"])
(defrecord User [name email place])
(apply ->User my-values)

; => #my-ns.User{:name "John",
                 :email "john@example.com",
                 :place "Dreamland"}
```