# Clojure: Assigning defrecord fields from Map

Tags: constructor, clojure

Following up on [How to make a record from a sequence of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514196/how-to-make-a-record-from-a-sequence-of-values), how can you write a `defrecord` constructor call and assign the fields from a `Map`, leaving un-named fields `nil`?

```
(defrecord MyRecord [f1 f2 f3])
(assign-from-map MyRecord {:f1 "Huey" :f2 "Dewey"})  ; returns a new MyRecord
```

I imagine a macro could be written to do this.

Comment: It should be mentioned that from clojure 1.3.0, you can do `(map->MyRecord {:f1 "Huey", :f2 "Dewey"})` or `#user.MyRecord{:f1 "Huey", :f2 "Dewey"}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply `merge` the map into a record initialised with `nil`s:

```
(merge (MyRecord. nil nil nil) {:f1 "Huey" :f2 "Dewey"})
```

Note that records are capable of holding values stored under extra keys in a map-like fashion.

The list of a record's fields can be obtained using reflection:

```
(defn static? [field]
  (java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isStatic
   (.getModifiers field)))

(defn get-record-field-names [record]
  (->> record
       .getDeclaredFields
       (remove static?)
       (map #(.getName %))
       (remove #{"__meta" "__extmap"})))
```

The latter function returns a seq of strings:

```
user> (get-record-field-names MyRecord)
("f1" "f2" "f3")
```

`__meta` and `__extmap` are the fields used by Clojure records to hold metadata and to support the map functionality, respectively.

You could write something like

```
(defmacro empty-record [record]
  (let [klass (Class/forName (name record))
        field-count (count (get-record-field-names klass))]
    `(new ~klass ~@(repeat field-count nil))))
```

and use it to create empty instances of record classes like so:

```
user> (empty-record user.MyRecord)
#:user.MyRecord{:f1 nil, :f2 nil, :f3 nil}
```

The fully qualified name is essential here. It's going to work as long as the record class has been declared by the time any `empty-record` forms referring to it are compiled.

If `empty-record` was written as a function instead, one could have it expect an actual class as an argument (avoiding the "fully qualified" problem -- you could name your class in whichever way is convenient in a given context), though at the cost of doing the reflection at runtime.

Comment: When the record implement a protocol, some other fields are added to the record. You can replace the last `remove` call of `get-record-field-names` by `(remove #(re-find #"__meta|__extmap|__cached" %))))`

Answer (score 6):

Clojure generates these days a *map->RecordType* function when a record is defined.

```
(defrecord Person [first-name last-name])
(def p1 (map->Person {:first-name "Rich" :last-name "Hickey"}))
```

The map is not required to define all fields in the record definition, in which case missing keys have a nil value in the result. The map is also allowed to contain extra fields that aren't part of the record definition.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the linked question responses, the [code here](https://github.com/david-mcneil/defrecord2) shows how to create a defrecord2 macro to generate a constructor function that takes a map, as demonstrated [here](http://david-mcneil.com/post/765563763/enhanced-clojure-records).  Specifically of interest is the [make-record-constructor](https://github.com/david-mcneil/defrecord2/blob/master/defrecord2.clj#L57) macro.