# Splicing unquote for non-literal sequences

Tags: macros, clojure

This question is a based on a limitation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514196/how-to-make-a-record-from-a-sequence-of-values/4514494#4514494).

If I have a macro that uses splicing unquote like this:

```
(defmacro instantiate [klass values] 
        `(new ~klass ~@values))
```

It will only work if `values` is a literal sequence or seq-able.

If it is passed a var holding a sequence like:

```
(def v [1 2 3]) 
(macroexpand '(instantiate Person v))
```

Then the output would be an error indicating that `v` is not a sequence.

Even a function call would be interpreted as a list:

```
(defn vf [] [1 2 3])
(macroexpand '(instantiate Person (vf)))
user=>(new Person vf)
```

My question is: Is there any way to use the splicing unquote in Clojure macros in those two cases where the sequence to be spliced isn't a literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros receive their arguments unevaluated, so the behavior you are seeing is as intended.

Macros are expanded at compile time, not run time. The values of any variables passed into a macro may not be available at compile time, so dirty hacks like using `eval` will not work in the general case. Don't create macros that require such tricks.

Comment: So, sometimes it's not possible, other times a bad idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

splicing quotes save a lot of time in almost all cases, except when they dont work, then you need to do things the old fashioned way...

```
(defmacro instantiate [klass values] 
    `(new ~klass ~@values))
```

could become

```
(defmacro instantiate [klass values] 
    (concat (list 'new klass) (if (seq? values) 
                                  values 
                                  (list values))))

user=> (macroexpand '(instantiate asdf (1 2 3)))
(new asdf 1 2 3)

user=>  (macroexpand '(instantiate asdf 1))
(new asdf 1)
```

Comment: It didn't solve my actual problem, as it was related to evaluation of parameters, but this did gave me an understanding of how splicing quotes actually work. Thanks