# Is there an apply function in Clojure for Java functions?

Tags: java, clojure

```
 user=> (Integer/rotateRight 0 0)
 0

 user=>  (apply Integer/rotateRight [0 0])
 CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: 
   rotateRight in class java.lang.Integer, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:172)
```

Is there any way to do apply for java functions in Clojure?  If not how could I write a macro or function that would support this?

Comment: Interesting: Plans to incorporate auto-method wrapper generation with a future Clojure compiler rewrite http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Better+method+inference

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest thing I can think of is wrapping it in a function, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the best/most idiomatic way:

```
user> (apply (fn [a b] (Integer/rotateRight a b)) [0 0])
0
```

Or, slightly shorter but equivalent:

```
user> (apply #(Integer/rotateRight %1 %2) [0 0])
0
```

Alternatively, you could create a proper wrapper function for your java method call:

```
(defn rotate-right [a b]
  (Integer/rotateRight a b))
```

You'd use it like so:

```
user> (apply rotate-right [0 0])
0
```

**edit**: just for fun, inspired by iradik's comment about efficieny, time comparisons between three different ways of calling this method:

```
;; direct method call (x 1 million)
user> (time (dorun (repeatedly 1E6 #(Integer/rotateRight 2 3))))
"Elapsed time: 441.326 msecs"
nil

;; method call inside function (x 1 million)
user> (time (dorun (repeatedly 1E6 #((fn [a b] (Integer/rotateRight a b)) 2 3))))
"Elapsed time: 451.749 msecs"
nil

;; method call in function using apply (x 1 million)
user> (time (dorun (repeatedly 1E6 #(apply (fn [a b] (Integer/rotateRight a b)) [2 3]))))
"Elapsed time: 609.556 msecs"
nil
```

Comment: that's pretty clever, i wonder if i could write a macro that wrote that for me.

Comment: you probably could, but personally I think the benefits of that are slim: the resulting form would hardly be shorter, and the code above makes it clear what's going on. Alternatively, you could define the function and call that instead of the java method. I'll edit my answer to illustrate.

Comment: I disagree. What if you could do (j-apply 'Integer/rotateRight [0 0])? Wouldn't that be more concise?

Comment: It would be more concise, but someone reading your code would need to figure out what j-apply means, so it's less readable, imho.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, but I don't want wrapper functions.  The reason I am asking is to find a way to do this that's both concise and yet efficient.

Comment: Hey I think I came up with a macro that does it:  (defmacro java-static-apply ([f] f) ([f args] `(~f ~@(map eval args)))). Called with (java-static-apply Integer/rotateRight [2 3]). The macro appears to get equivalent performance with (Integer/rotateRight 2 3). What do you think?  My biggest issue with this macro is it doesn't work for new (ex: (new Integer 3) and method calls (.hashCode my-int).  So not a general solution.

Comment: @iradik No, if you get `eval` involved the solution is immediately horrible. Given the above macro definition, try (for example) `(let [x "10"] (java-static-apply Integer/parseInt [x]))` - you will find `x` is not in scope. Worse still, this macro only works if you have a *literal seq at compile-time* - which is exactly the time when you don't need apply at all! It won't work at all with `(let [args ["10"]] (java-static-apply Integer/parseInt args))`, because it can't map over the args at compile-time.

Comment: This works for map, too. `(map #(Integer/parseInt %) ["1" "2" "3"])`

Answer (score 4):

A couple of points which, while not a direct answer, are relevant here.

First off, Java does not have functions. It only has either instance methods or static methods. This may seem like a pedantic distinction, but it does make a difference (as shown in some of the other examples where different forms are needed for static and instance invocation).

Secondly, the impedance mismatch between the type systems comes into play. For Java to have fully-fledged FP support in a Javaish manner, it would need to be statically typed. This turns out to be quite hard to do in a truly satisfactory manner (see the discussion on the lambda-dev mailing list for details of the approach that is being used and will arrive in Java 8).

From these two points, we can see that from Clojure the best we can really do is to support an "all bets are off" approach to calling Java methods via #() or similar. Clojure will only choose between forms to call based on the arity of the argument, so some sort of type hints or casting may be needed to ensure the correct overloaded Java method is called.

More importantly, of course, if a user passes an argument of a type that Java isn't expecting, or can't handle, this may not be detectable until runtime.

Comment: right. I would like to know how to call an instance-method on a seq of instances.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a few macros to do this after being inspired by gertalot's answer.  Appears to compile to the equivalent normal code.  Benchmark was identical.  Curious what you think.

```
(defmacro java-new-apply 
   ([klass] `(new ~klass))
   ([klass args] `(new ~klass ~@(map eval args))))

(defmacro java-static-apply 
   ([f] f)
   ([f args] `(~f ~@(map eval args))))

(defmacro java-method-apply 
   ([method obj] method obj) 
   ([method obj args] `(~method ~obj ~@(map eval args))))

;; get date for Jan 1 1969
(import java.util.Date)
(java-new-apply Date [69 1 1])
(macroexpand '(java-new-apply Date [69 1 1]))
(new Date 69 1 1)

(java-static-apply Integer/rotateRight [2 3])
(macroexpand '(java-static-apply Integer/rotateRight [2 3]))
(. Integer rotateRight 2 3)

(java-method-apply .substring "hello world!" [6 11])
(macroexpand '(java-method-apply .substring "hello world!" [6 11]))
(. "hello world!" substring 6 11)
```

Comment: This works only if you pass literals to your macros. Try this: `(def my-date-data [69 1 1])(macroexpand '(java-new-apply Date my-date-data))` to see that it doesn't work. Macros are expanded at compile time, not run time, which means that you don't have access to the actual values which are passed.

Comment: I [tried the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514494/506721) and eventually found out that it just isn't worth it compared to the idiomatic solution with wrapper functions.

Comment: Agree with Goran - no matter how you slice it, you'll always end up with a method call wrapped inside a function call.

Comment: oh too good to be true i suppose. yes you're right, and yes i want real data.